# pandas - resample - upsampling before downsampling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with information on different timescales, i.e. for some periods I have 100 data points per second and for other periods I have 1 data point every minute.

My objective is to resample this data frame with a fixed time window (e.g.: 1 second) using last for regularization when upsampling and the mean for downsampling.

In addition, I wish to specify the order in which the algorithm performs both operations (downsampling and upsampling) because I need upsampling (using last) to be performed first and downsampling (using mean) to be performed only afterwards.

Is this possible at all using pandas resample function?

For example, in the sample code below, I would like the following values in the resulting data frame: 0.5 (mean) between 0 and 10 seconds, 0 (last) between 10 and 19 seconds, and 10 between 19 and 39 seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value' : np.repeat(1,10)}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01 00:00:00', periods=10, freq='1S'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value' : np.repeat(0,10)}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01 00:00:00.5', periods=10, freq='1S'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'value' : np.repeat(10,3)}, index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01 00:00:19', periods=3, freq='10S'))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0)
df = df.sort_index()

df.resample(rule='1S', fill_method='ffill', kind='timestamp', how='mean')
```

How do you suggest that I tackle this problem?

EDIT: My real data frame is large, therefore I'd like to minimize the number of operations, especially those which involve object copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your traditional resampling with downsampling:

```
df_new = df.resample(rule='1S')
```

Followed by upsampling where you `update` your down sampled data, but don't overwrite it. You are filling in the blanks with the fill forward upsampled data:

```
df_new.update(df.resample(rule='1S', fill_method='ffill', kind='timestamp', how='last'), 
              overwrite=False)

>>> df_new
                     value
2010-01-01 00:00:00    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:01    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:02    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:03    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:04    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:05    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:06    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:07    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:08    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:09    0.5
2010-01-01 00:00:10    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:11    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:12    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:13    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:14    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:15    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:16    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:17    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:18    0.0
2010-01-01 00:00:19   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:20   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:21   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:22   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:23   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:24   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:25   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:26   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:27   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:28   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:29   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:30   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:31   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:32   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:33   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:34   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:35   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:36   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:37   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:38   10.0
2010-01-01 00:00:39   10.0
```

You can't mix upsample/downsample in a single `resample` operation.  I'm not sure why the order of operations would matter to you as long as you get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was not clear to me that you had to make multiple calls to resample.

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas depreciated the `how=` and `fill_method=` arguments in 0.18.0 the new syntax would be:

```
df_new = df.resample(rule='1S').mean()
df_new.update(df.resample(rule='1S').ffill(), overwrite=False)
```